# SQL 2008 - Local only connections

Tags: sql-server

I'm running SQL 2008 on a Rackspace VM.  I want to lock it down so that SQL will only accept connections from processes on the local machine, can I configure this in SQL itself or is it a firewall task? Also, I have a vague recollection of reading somewhere that using (local) in the connection string of the client app. rather than an IP address enables the connection to 'short-circuit' the network stack and thus delivers a performance increase, is this the case?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you can disable TCP/IP in the SQL Server Configuration Manager. It is also a good idea to use Windows Firewall as well on any web-facing server as well. Defense in depth, and all that.

Answer (score 1):

As for connectivity, go to the SQL Server Configuration Manager and disable the TCP/IP and Named Pipes protocols. Local connections (on the host itself) will use the Shared Memory protocol.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892(v=sql.105).aspx